# Navigation works first after second click

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish

i wonder why my navigation works first after the second click on a menu item.
But its just when i restarted the application. after that evertthing works fine as it should.

My guess is that it has something to do with the creation of the backing bean. Here is some relevant code:

**menu**

```
<p:menubar>
    <p:submenu label="SMS" icon="ui-icon-contact">
    <p:menuitem value="send SMS" action="#{smsb.smsInit}"></p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="SMS preferences" action="#{smsb.smsprefsInit}"></p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Senaste utskick" action="#{sb.latestCall}"></p:menuitem>
```

smsb.init is a method to clear some variables and lists

```
public String smsInit(){

teachers = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
this.fillTeacherList();
    return "gotosmsprepare";
}
```

in the faces-config navigation

```
<navigation-rule>  
<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>gotosmsprepare</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/Teacher/prepareSMS.xhtml</to-view-id>
   </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
```

as mentioned, everything work after the second click.

Any help or hint?

Regards
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too, adding `ajax="false"` in `p:menuItem`, it works for me